# Log user activity to file in Django

Tags: python, django, logging

I would like to log all changes to a file that the user makes. Users change data mostly with generic views. (DeleteView, UpdateView, CreateView) and I must be able to track all changes.

For example:

```
[timestamp] User: [username] added [all] [additions] [to] [database] [here]

[timestamp] User: [username] deleted [all] [deleted] [fields]

[timestamp] User: [username] edited [old] [fields] to [new] [data] [fields]
```

There could be even more info (like users full name etc.) but I atleast try to keep the question simple. Also the log must work in production for obvious reasons. So far what I've found is about logging error messages etc. to files or console. Does anybody have any idea where to start?

Comment: Here is a good tutorial: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html If you have specific questions, please ask them.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [`django-reversion`](https://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It is, I would say, one of the more popular solution for auditing changes.

The most basic usage example, would look like:

1. register your model with reversion:

   ```
   import reversion

   @reversion.register()
   class YourModel(models.Model):
       # ...
       pass
   ```
2. Record all changes in views via [it's middleware](https://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/middleware.html):

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += ('reversion.middleware.RevisionMiddleware', )
   ```
3. *(OR)* Record changes by [decorating specific views](https://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/views.html):

   ```
   from reversion.views import RevisionMixin

   class RevisionFormView(RevisionMixin, FormView):
       # ...
       pass
   ```
4. *(AND/OR)* Record changes with [the context manager](https://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#creating-revisions):

   ```
   with reversion.create_revision():

       # Save a new model instance.
       obj = YourModel()
       obj.name = "obj v1"
       obj.save()

       # Store some meta-information.
       reversion.set_user(request.user)
       reversion.set_comment("Created revision 1")
   ```

Comment: Wherever you make changes to your model instance, that you want to be recorded. (it could be a model method, a view, a form method, etc)